# Find the difference between two arrays based on some the value inside a nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have two arrays

```
arrayOfItems: [
    {
    id: '4321-3321-4423', 
    value: 'some text'
    },

    {
    id: '4322-4654-9875', 
    value: 'some text again'
    }
]
```

Then the second array

```
itemX: [
    {
    id: '3214-6543-4321', 
    nestedArrayOfItems:[
        {id: '4321-3321-4423'}
        {id: '3455-8765-7764'}
    ]
    }
]
```

I need to create a new array based on `arrayOfItems` that doesn't include any of the id's in the `itemX.nestedArrayOfItems`

Because of it being a nested Array I'm drawing a blank on what I need to do... I'm searching through Lodash to see if there is something that doesn't involve me using a bunch of for loops.

Comment: `4321-3321-4423` should be a string as it's not a valid number. In JS `4321-3321-4423` will become `-3423` as `-` is subtraction

Comment: That's the one thing I forgot to add, but yes, they are strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` and then check if the id exists with
`Array.prototype.some()` like so:

```js
const arrayOfItems = [
  {
  id: '4321-3321-4423', 
  value: 'some text'
  },

  {
  id: '4322-4654-9875', 
  value: 'some text again'
  }
]

const itemX = [
  {
  id: '3214-6543-4321', 
  nestedArrayOfItems: [
      {id: '4321-3321-4423'},
      {id: '3455-8765-7764'}
  ]
  }
]

const res = arrayOfItems.filter(item => !itemX[0].nestedArrayOfItems.some(({ id }) => id === item.id))

console.log(res);
```

Comment: You are correct, but I also found out I was wrong. turns out the keys in `nestedArrayOfItems` could be anything, usually a number 0 to ### and weren't `id` after.

Answer (score 0):

how about this :

```
let difference = arrayOfItems.filter(x => ! itemX.nestedArrayOfItems.includes(x));
```

PS : ids must be string

Comment: This seems to spit out an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

Comment: itemX is an array, it's itemX[0]